# jquery:how linking the menubar to tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, menubar

I have a menubar and tabs the code like below:

```
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Inspection</span></a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span>show tabs1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>show tabs2</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>    

    <div id="tabs">
          <ul>
               <li><a href="#tabs1">Inspection Report</a></li>
               <li><a href="#tabs2">Input Data</a></li>
          </ul>
      <div id="tabs1">
           bla bla bla
      </div>
      <div id="tabs2">
           blah blah blah
      </div>
   </div>
```

i have use this code below for selected tabs.
but after i have clicked `show tabs1`, actually show `tabs2`:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#Tabs").tabs();
              $("#menu ul li a").each(function(index){
                        $(this).click(function(){
                                  $("#Tabs").tabs("select",index);
                                  });
                         });
             });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: i've been change my question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you finally have provided enough information, it's easier to help you...

Edit your javascript to the following, it still uses the [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253989/jqueryhow-linking-the-menubar-to-tabs/3264648#3264648) method of jQuery tabs

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#menu a:not(:first)").each(function(index){
        $(this).click(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs("select",index);
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LdDGG

---

Alternatively, if you plan on adding more `a` elements into your `#menu`, you should add IDs to either the `a` elements or the `ul`, like in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LdDGG/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but maybe the `select` method is what you're looking for.
It does the following:

> Select a tab, as if it were clicked.
>   The second argument is the zero-based
>   index of the tab to be selected or the
>   id selector of the panel the tab is
>   associated with (the tab's href
>   fragment identifier, e.g. hash, points
>   to the panel's id).

Also from the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/):

> [How do I]...select a tab from a text link
>   instead of clicking a tab itself

```
var $tabs = $('#example').tabs(); // first tab selected

$('#my-text-link').click(function() { // bind click event to link
        $tabs.tabs('select', 2); // switch to third tab
        return false;
});
```

Here's a demo of how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/hP9xb/

Comment: no..i'm just asking...can i directly open the second tab after choose at menubar

Comment: what happens now when you do that (choose at menubar)? can you put up a demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar? It's not very clear what you want

Comment: Well, you pasted my code into your question. You didn't really do anything else. It's not any more clear what you want and how your page is structured

Answer (score 0):

We'll call your menu the "tab console" and your main container the "tab pane."

Let's say your tab console's html looks something like this:

```
<ul id="tab_console">
    <li id="first"><a href="#">My First Page</a></li>
    <li id="second"><a href="#">My Second Page</a></li>
    <li id="third"><a href="#">My Third Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

... and your tab pane's lookw like this:

```
<div id="tab_pane">
    <div id="page_first"></div>
    <div id="page_second"></div>
    <div id="page_this"></div>
</div>
```

You would need to hide the various tab pane contents, so they don't all show at once. You can do this with CSS:

```
#tab_pane div {display: none;}
```

Now we need a script to make it all work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                    // fires when browser loads your html
    $('#tab_console > li').click(function() {    // fires when a tab is clicked
        $('#tab_pane > div').hide();             // hides all tab contents
        $('#tab_pane > #page_' + $(this).attr('id')).show();   // show the selected tab
    });

    $('#tab_pane > li#page_first').show();     // load your default tab
});
```